# wget ftp an entire site is very slow

Tags: php, ftp, wget

I'm trying to wget an entire site to transfer from Server A to Server B.
It works, but incredibly slowly.

I tested this by uploading a 100mb psd file to my server, and grabbing it with wget ftp. Transfer speeds were 26.76mb/sec.

But when I try and grab the whole site (minus the psd file) it takes 5 minutes to transfer 92mb of html files. It's a wordpress install with a theme and images basically.

Is this because it opens a new connection for each file? 
I tried doing this with php's ftp library, but that took just as long if not longer.

scp, ssh are not an option because 98% of the time I don't own the server, so I have to work with some sort of ftp.
I'm using:

```
wget -r ftp://user:pass@domain.com/dir is what I'm using.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is always slower to transfer many files than it is to transfer one big file.  Zip the contents of your website and the transfer will go much faster.  You can use `tar` to do this.

Comment: Can't zip, as I don't know if Server A has the library for it, and I don't have access other than ftp. I supposed I could log into the server, transfer a php file that would zip the contents, transfer that zip file, then delete with php file with unlink(_SELF_); or something.

Answer (score 0):

`wget` will try to keep the connection open, but even with a single connection there is a significant overhead at the server end to serve each request, which is most probably what's causing the slowdown you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

It's not as simple as `-r` I admit but you could try this: Make a list of the files, separate this list in e.g. six parts and start wget six times simultaneously each with a part of the list. A short look at the cumulated transfer speed should tell you whether the number of files is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can't speed up the transfer since it does a connection for each file, but try [ftpcopy](http://ohse.de/uwe/ftpcopy.html) which allows you to mirror an ftp

from ftpcopy site:

> Speed
>
> ftpcopy needed about 110 seconds to copy my site. Subsequent runs
>   which don't need to copy anything take about 1.04 seconds. mirror
>   needed about 250 seconds to copy my site. Subsequent runs which don't
>   need to copy anything take about 2.6 seconds.